# Many proper sub projects in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode5

I am working on a project which contains many sub projects, the sub projects are proper full fledge projects containing many view controllers and all project related things (i.e. they are not static libraries.) So I want one main project from which I want to invoke several other projects.

For example I have a ProjectMain with ViewController1, SubProject1 with ViewController2, SubProject3 with ViewController3.

I have two buttons on ViewController1 launching ViewController2 and ViewController3 respectively.

First of all, is it possible? And if it is, how should I achieve it? I have searched the internet but cannot find anything except adding static libraries to project.

Comment: first of all why you want them as separate projects , why can't you include all viewcontrollers into one? I mean is there any specific reason?

Comment: yes because they are all developed as separate projects, and now it is not possible to make it into one project with so many viewcontrollers, many conflicts may occur, and I don't want to dive in solving those conflicts.

Comment: Have you looked into using a workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dependency of the project by drag-n-droping all the project, you want to add into your project and than you have to add Header Search Paths,This is a list of paths to folders to be searched by the compiler for included or imported user header files.

This may help you, [go here](http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/03/specifying-the-build-configuration-for-xcode-project-dependencies/)

and Also you can use `xcodeworkspace` as well to achieving what you want. 
[here is apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ProjectsWorkspaces/start_project.html) for reference

Comment: Can I then perform segue between ViewController1 and ViewController2 they both belong to different projects.

Comment: they may belong to different project but when you used them all in one, than yes you can go from any viewController to any and use segue to pass data.